# Select and Multiple select is not working

Tags: html, css, material-design

I am using [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) for designing my website.
But when I am using

```
 <div class="input-field col s12">
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<label>Materialize Select</label>
```

For single selection

And

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
<select multiple>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
```

For multiple selections.

But it is not working totally.

If I use

```
<label>Browser Select</label>
 <select class="browser-default">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

This browser default class, this is working fine. But I need the top two styles.

Anyone can help?

Comment: try.... <select multiple="multiple">

Comment: I just tried not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materialize with multiple works if you declare the proper JS function. Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select').material_select();
});
```

See the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/vLPNga)